# PHP Cron.Hourly needs mysql driver

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I want to run an hourly php script that updates my mysql server. I put the scripts into a folder `/etc/cron.hourly`. But I am getting an error.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$connection=new pdo('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE','ROOT','PASS');
$prepare=$connection->prepare('update TABLE set COLUMN=COLUMN+?');
$prepare->execute([1]);
?>
```

I keep getting this error.

[image]

How do I get the mysql part of the php to work as well? Is there a directory to connect mysql driver to the file as well?

Comment: Check in your phpinfo() if you have a pdo_mysql driver else install `php5-mysql` or `php7-mysql` linux package.

Comment: Yes thank you! I didn't realize I didn't have the php-mysql installed itself. Thanks Oscar!

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check so that the driver is installed. This can be done by check the output of `phpInfo()` or using php cli:

```
phpInfo();
```

or:

```
php -m
```

If not installed then simply install it and restart apache:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```